# Random natural number within range function Typescript returns me not so random numbers

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, random

I am currently working on a function which is supposed to generate numbers within a specific range. Example: If the minimum of the range is 1 and the maximum is  5 then it should return a number between 1 and 5 or equal to 1 and 5.

This is the code I have so far:

```
function getRandomNumber(min: number, max: number): number {
    max = max + 1; // in order to include the max value
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}
```

This function does work as intended but unfortunately some numbers get generated quite often in sequence. Example: I define a range of 1 to 5, the output of the function will be something like: `1,1,1,1,1,5,5,5,1,1,1,1,5,1,1,1,5,1,1,4,4,2,2,3,1,1,1,1,5,1,5,1,5,5,1,1,1,1,3`

As we can see all the numbers of the range are being included but for some reason certain numbers e.g 1 and 5 in this case get generated often in sequence and are generally being generated more often than they should to be classified as 'random' (imo).

My question is if I have done anything wrong in my code or if this is supposed to be normal behavior.

Comment: Works fine for me and gives more or less even distribution. How do you use this function?

Comment: That's how randomness works. You can't just look at the numbers at tell if they came from an RNG or not.

Comment: My results after a 1,000,000,000 iterations: `{1 => 200004750, 2 => 199990567, 3 => 199986422, 4 => 200008385, 5 => 200009876}`. Seems pretty well distributed

Comment: Ok, i guess my problem was that my "input size" was too low. I've been calling it like 25 times max and it seems that only the first few numbers tend to have this problem. Or my machine is busted somehow lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is equally distributed ...

```js
function getRandomNumber(min, max) {
    max = max + 1;
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

const count = { 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0 };

for (let i = 0; i < 1e6; i++) count[getRandomNumber(1, 5)]++;

console.log(count);
```